# legality of unpacking minified javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that this is more of a legal question but I thought I'd give this a shot.

I am learning javascript and I found some interesting drop down menu's on a webpage. I wanted to learn more about them but the code is minified with the following in the comments above the minified code:

> `// Unauthorized decryption/reproduction of any codes contained herein is strictly prohibited and will result in severe civil and criminal penalties.`

Is it really illegal for me to unpack the code and look through it? Can I be sued for looking at code without actually using it?

Comment: Off topic, but honestly? I'd just deobfuscate and ignore the threats, if it's running on my machine I feel a right to see what it's doing.

Comment: Looking at it doesn't really constitute "decryption."

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "warning" has little legal bearing beyond normal copyright law, and aside from anything that's protected by a patent (which is very unlikely in JavaScript code), you're free to look at and learn from it. If there is patented content (again, very unlikely), you can still learn how it works; using it might not be legal.

Comment: +1 for a decent question.  Unfortunately, i also have to vote to close as off topic.  We generally don't deal with legal stuff here.  You might have better luck on http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If you're a beginner it would surely be easier to find an open source example to study, there are plenty about. I think you have to be familiar with a language before you can de-obfuscate.

Comment: I'd be curious to look at the code you're talking about so that I can make fun of it for not being worth stealing in the first place.

Comment: http://live.intersoftpt.com/Default.aspx?p=/WebCombo

If you look at some of the menus on this page you will see what I am talking about. Specifically look at "multiple columns" and how they have basically displayed table data in a drop down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>**IANAL**</sub>

Minification is *not* encryption. You already have permission to copy the file to your machine and open it (as your browser requires these permissions to use it). There is no legal protection for examining the contents of a file that's freely available. You can even modify it on your own system at will, these sorts of copyright allowances fall under [fair use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) because you're doing so for educational purposes.

What you *can't* do is distribute the file or the modified file.

Answer (score 6):

I'm no expert, but if there were anything criminal about viewing a website's source code, then browsers would not make it so easy.

While I can definitely say that *using* someone else's code without permission is wrong, I think it's a great thing to learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

In my honest opinion, it shouldn't (and probably isn't) illegal to look at the code since it's open to anyone.

Using and learning from the source code are two completely different things.
Using someone's work without their permission is simply wrong no matter what the context is (code, images, art, etc).

But learning from other source code is probably the best way to learn and get better.

As for their legal note, I think they just put that there to scare people off but I don't think it would stand in court.